# Why doesn't the heading 'Glossary' appear like the word 'Index'?

Tags: titles, memoir, glossaries

I'm trying to get the word Glossary to appear as a heading on the page where the glossary is printed in the same way that the word Index is generated for indexed words. The later is automatically generated but the former isn't.
I am using TexStudio and have used the Tools to compile twice F5 then F9 to run the glossary then F5 twice as recommended.
What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeglossary
\newglossaryentry{cabbage}{name=Cabbage,description={Green vegetable often over cooked}}
\begin{document}
    Word to add to Glossary \gls{cabbage}. 
    Word to add to index\index{bacon} bacon.
\printglossary
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` compiler made from Perl script if I remember right.

Comment: As @M.A.Bromuela mentioned you need to run `makeglossaries`. I don't know if `imakeidx` can be told to run `makeglossaries` as well, I just ran `makeglossaries` by hand and the missing pages appear at the next compilation.

Comment: Could you please signpost me to how I could 'run...from Perl script', or 'run makeglossaries by hand'.

Comment: I have just compiled it in Overleaf and it works fine, though I do get a warning that \makeglossary is deprecated and to use \makeglosaries instead, so I'm guessing it must be something to do with TexStudio.